# Webots Ros2 Docker Extern controller plugin silently crashes when asking for keyboard

Tags: ros, ros2, webots

I am using webots 2022b inside of a docker container. In my vs code, it runs fine, but when I try to run the command straight from the docker container, I am running into an issue where the controller program instantly exits with code-11 but no output or error message.

```
[ERROR] [driver-2]: process has died [pid 66, exit code -11, cmd '/opt/ros/galactic/lib/webots_ros2_driver/driver __log_level:=debug --log-level debug --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_ec8xrm55'].
```

With rclcpp print statements, I have narrowed the crash down to occur on this line:

```
keyboard_ = node_->robot()->getKeyboard();
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple days now; I have a couple directions the solution may go: either enable some lower level of logging that will let me see an error message I can work with (I have tried adding
`arguments=[('__log_level:=debug'), '--log-level', 'debug']` to the driver node in the launch file but those don't seem to work),

or alternatively maybe there is some setting in docker I can give to pass the keyboard through to the container in a way that webots expects? I have tried a couple things like using docker run -it to give terminal emulation.

Comment: If it crashes at the line you indicate, it probably means that `node_->robot()` returns `NULL`. Can you check if it is the case?

Comment: @OlivierMichel I don't think so, in previous lines I have several things like `camera_ = node_->robot()->getCamera("CAM");` which work fine. However, I will explicitly check for you

Comment: @OlivierMichel Yep I checked an it is not == nullptr, I can also rclcpp output `node_->robot()->getName()` and get a correct result (in this case our companyname+robot)

Comment: That's very odd since the [getKeyboard](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/d02be09b76f545d0bda919b471349af03a04159e/include/controller/cpp/webots/Robot.hpp#L108) method is extremely simple and cannot crash normally... So, I would suspect that you compiled with a version of libController and you are executing it with a different version. Could it be the case?

Comment: I'm not really sure what libController is, looks like its a sub-section of the webots repo. But both my development stage and my running stage originate from https://hub.docker.com/layers/cyberbotics/webots/R2022b-ubuntu20.04/images/sha256-18c731dccfecc377f50ca4aea359b297f7546ef14cf057fd16233b151fb80092?context=explore 

so I think it should be the same?

Comment: It's not clear to me what `getKeyboard` is supposed to do here (zero experience with webots), but I don't know how a docker container would have a keyboard. I would strongly suspect your issue has something to do with being in a docker container, but I can't tell why the robot would have a keyboard to get or why one would be available in a docker container. I would think the process would be the other way, that you would set a keyboard to pass inputs to a robot. Again though, no experience here, but there's also no extra code to give context or any links to documentation here for us to read.

Comment: @Chuck thanks. Here the documentation would be at https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot?tab-language=c++ - under wb_robot_get_device. It should return an instance of a https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/keyboard?tab-language=c++ Webots is simulation software, and the keyboard here is a convenient way to get input that it provides. It's also open source: you can see the method being called here at line 108 https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/blob/master/webots_ros2_driver/webots/include/controller/cpp/webots/Robot.hpp
I agree its to do with docker, Just dont know what

Comment: It seems you are using both a Webots docker and the webots_ros2 package. Are they running inside the same docker? I am still convinced that there may be a version mismatch between Webots (you are using Webots R2022b) and the ROS 2 package [webots_ros2 for galactic](https://index.ros.org/p/webots_ros2/#galactic) which is currently version 2023.0.0 corresponding to Webots R2023a. Could you please better explain how you put together Webots and webots_ros2? Can you share your `Dockerfile`s if any?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that as Oliver Michel had said, there was a version mismatch between the compiling version of webots and the executing. In this case, it was as simple as I was colcon building in a window of vs code that I had opened weeks ago, and as such was still using webots 2022a, even though I had long since updated the dockerfile to force using 2022b.

Compiling with one version and running against another perhaps predictably caused these unusual errors. Rebuilding my vscode container so I could colcon build in the newer version solved my problem.